# Which to upgrade first? Ruby to 1.9.2 or Rails to 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Running `rails 2.3.14` without any warnings on `ruby 1.8.7-p371`.  What's next?  Should I upgrade `ruby` to `1.9.2` or should I upgrade `rails` to `3.0`?

A quick search seems to suggest that `rails 2.3.14` is not compatible with `ruby 1.9.2`. ([1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-core/eRYpBZI0MAU), [2](http://instantbadger.blogspot.com/2011/11/porting-rails-23-app-to-ruby-19.html), [3](http://splatoperator.com/2011/08/running-rails-2-3-14-on-ruby-1-9-2/)).  Is this true?

On the other hand, it sounds like `rails 3.x` runs on `ruby 1.8.7`. ([4](http://paulbarry.com/articles/2009/09/14/why-rails-3-will-require-ruby-1-8-7))

Comment: 1) What mu said. 2) Yes, Rails 3.x runs on Ruby 1.8.7, but Rails 4 won't, and some gems are already requiring Ruby 1.9. So either way, you'll want to update both

Comment: Indeed you should upgrade both, but I would strongly suggest doing them one at time. Introducing two major version bumps in each of framework and language dramatically expands the search space you need to consider as you try to understand any behavior regressions induced by the change. You seem to have already investigated the compatibility issues which dictate you should move to Rails 3 before upgrading the ruby.

Comment: lol why are these comments and not answers ...

Comment: In the end, I upgraded rails straight to 3.2, deployed to production, and *then* a few weeks later upgraded ruby to 1.9.3.  I would recommend this order of steps to others still on rails 2.